# Template is not loading showing error [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Tags: vuejs2

I'm loading default listing using vuejs. When I browse page it show me following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
```

My html template is as bellow:

```
<template id="results-template">
    <div class="results-wrap col-lg-8 col-md-8 ">
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        <div v-for="category in books" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pl-0">
            <div class="single-vertical-book box">
                <div class="book mt-20 text-center">                   
                    <img v-bind:src="{{category.URL}}" />
                    <div class="book-title-latest">
                        <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="$parent.filterCats($event)" v-bind:data-hash="category.id">{{category.Title}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book-author-lastest">
                        <a href="#" v-if="(category.Category == result.id)" v-for="(result,key) in genres" v-bind:key="result.id">
                            {{result.name}}
                        </a>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm using API to get data. When I inspected API response it's showing me response correctly but vuejs is not showing data in template. My VueJs code is as bellow:

```
Vue.component('Results',{
              template : '#results-template',
              props: ['books','genres']
          })
```

and VueJs method is as bellow:

```
getBooks : function(){
          var vm = this;
          return $.get('apis.php?gtype=Books')
                        .done(function(d){
                             vm.books    = JSON.parse(d);
                            });
                        }
```

My created on loading page code is as bellow:

```
created : function(){
                        var vm = this;
                        this.getBooks().done(function(){
                           ........
                        });
                    }
```

Code for data :

```
data : {
          books : []
         }
```

Please help me what's wrong I'm doing?

Comment: can you place your created code here as well that's in VueJs

Comment: Ok let me edit my post and add created code also

Comment: I've added created code as well please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are binding image incorrect way first of all make it correct. Replace your code:

```
<template id="results-template">
    <div class="results-wrap col-lg-8 col-md-8 ">
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        <div v-for="category in books" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pl-0">
            <div class="single-vertical-book box">
                <div class="book mt-20 text-center">                   
                    <img :src="category.URL" />
                    <div class="book-title-latest">
                        <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="$parent.filterCats($event)" v-bind:data-hash="category.id">{{category.Title}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book-author-lastest">
                        <a href="#" v-if="(category.Category == result.id)" v-for="(result,key) in genres" v-bind:key="result.id">
                            {{result.name}}
                        </a>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

with this code:

```
<template id="results-template">
    <div class="results-wrap col-lg-8 col-md-8 ">
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        <div v-for="category in books" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pl-0">
            <div class="single-vertical-book box">
                <div class="book mt-20 text-center">                   
                    <img v-bind:src="{{category.URL}}" />
                    <div class="book-title-latest">
                        <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="$parent.filterCats($event)" v-bind:data-hash="category.id">{{category.Title}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book-author-lastest">
                        <a href="#" v-if="(category.Category == result.id)" v-for="(result,key) in genres" v-bind:key="result.id">
                            {{result.name}}
                        </a>
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

You've to use **:src="category.URL"** for image src binding not :src="{{category.URL}}" 
Secondly in template call you are using **"genres"** have you initialized genres array or not? this may also cause for error. 1st check both of causes if problem not solved the check further.

Comment: Yes I'm using genres array as also